# Add missing rows within a table

Tags: sql, hana

I need a hint please, in my table it can happen that positions of an order is not written to the next ID.

Let's look at the table:

Pos 2 is missing in ID 3

| ID | DOC | POSI | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 123 | 2 | 600 |
| 1 | 123 | 3 | 200 |
| 2 | 123 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 123 | 2 | 600 |
| 2 | 123 | 3 | 200 |
| 3 | 123 | 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 123 | 3 | 200 |

Is it possible to create a view using SQL that compares the individual IDs partitions with each other and appends the missing value from ID 2 to ID 3 as a row?

Maybe you have some keywords for me, if something like this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint would be: Use a join.

One way of approaching this is, that you select the key pairs that you expect and then left join the original table. Be conscious about the missing-value handling, since you have not specified in your question what should happen to those newly created entries.

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER, doc INTEGER, posi INTEGER, total INTEGER);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 123, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 123, 2, 600);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 123, 3, 200);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 123, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 123, 2, 600);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 123, 3, 200);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 123, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 123, 3, 200);
```

**The possible key combinations can be generated with a cross join:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.posi 
FROM test a, test b
```

**And now join the original table:**

```
WITH expected_lines AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.posi 
    FROM test a, test b
)
SELECT el.id, el.posi, t.doc, t.total
FROM expected_lines el
LEFT JOIN test t ON el.id = t.id AND el.posi = t.posi
```

You did not describe further, what should happen with the now empty columns. As you may note `DOC` and `TOTAL` are `null`.

My educated guess would be, that you want to make `DOC` part of the key and assume a `TOTAL` of `0`. If that's the case, you can go with the following:

```
WITH expected_lines AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.posi, c.doc 
    FROM test a, test b, test c
)
SELECT el.id, el.posi, el.doc, ifnull(t.total, 0) total
FROM expected_lines el
LEFT JOIN test t ON el.id = t.id AND el.posi = t.posi AND el.doc = t.doc
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Hi @Mathias, thank you! That's almost what I need, also to overwrite the NULL value in the first step with a 0 is ok, in the next step I use a LAG() OVER() function and get the differences between the Posi and IDs. As I do not know how to post a scrrenshot in a comment I attach it on the main post. I thnik the problem ist that I calculate with the NULL value not with the 0.

Comment: I am assuming, that you've applied `ifnull(total, 0)` for the projection (so you have a 0 in the screenshot), but you've not applied it in the calculation of field `OE`?

Comment: hi, thank you! I did the `partition by` on the wrong table, changed to el. now its fine! Thanks alot!